# Wher to look for custom teplate tag in django

Tags: django, django-custom-tags, netbox

I'm trying to understand how netbox application is working (https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox). In a template "sidenav.html" it uses a custom tag "nav" this way:

```
{% load nav %}
{% nav %}
```

Can you tell me what's behind that and where or how can I find it?

Comment: It'll likely be a `templatetags/nav.py` somewhere.

Comment: Got it: /opt/netbox/netbox/utilities/templatetags/nav.py. How django knows where to look for?

Comment: I would assume `netbox.utilities` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.